# Sort a String Array containing Numbers in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have following string array which contain numbers
`string[] arr = { "3", "1", "6", "10", "5", "13" };`
if i do `arr.OrderBy(x=>x)` i am getting following result
1 
10 
13 
3 
5 
6 
expected result(in array):
1
3
5
6
10
13
 Any one have better and simple solution.

Comment: arr.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray(); its helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you do a `string` comparison - you should change that to a `int` comparison

```
string[] arr = { "3", "1", "6", "10", "5", "13" };
var result = arr.OrderBy(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: i need result in array so as  @un-lucky said need to convert to array..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `int.Parse()` inside LINQ like the following:

```
var resultArray = arr.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

You can checkout this [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1f5MM5)

Comment: why you are using lambda to parse and why you want to convert to array if already its array..

Comment: @Arunkumar: the result of OrderBy is not Array, its `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, So I'm using `.ToArray` to make it as an array. it is a new information for me that `arr.OrderBy(int.Parse)` will do the same job. Thanks to Toshi

Comment: arr.OrderBy(int.Parse).ToArray();

Comment: you didnt tell why you are using lambda to parse